# What's the correct use of RKObjectManager for PUT?

Tags: ios, restkit, put

I'm working with an API which allows updating of objects with PUT requests - with the following format (w/ curl):

```
curl --request PUT -u <api_key>: <api_url> \
-d "attribute=newvalue"
```

i.e. any attributes of the associated object (referenced in the API url) which are listed in the curl are then updated, and the updated object is returned.

I'm using RestKit with mapped objects, and everything works dandy with GET. But after updating attributes in the mapped objects, I'm struggling to get the putObject method in RKObjectManager to work, e.g.:

```
 [objectManager putObject:<someObject>
               path:path
               parameters:nil
               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {}
               failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
               }
 ];
```

Whatever I put in as the first parameter - an updated mapped object, a JSONified dictionary, even just a plain old body string, seems to return a "Could not parse request data, invalid JSON" error from RestKit. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<someObject>` should be an instance of a class from your data model. The class must have a defined set of mappings.

Say you had a class `Person`. You define a mapping and a response descriptor so RestKit can convert downloaded JSON into `Person` objects. Now, you need to obtain the `inverseMapping` to define your request descriptor so RestKit knows how to serialise for upload.

This allows RestKit to take your `<someObject>`, serialise it into JSON (request descriptor), send it to your server and then receive a response and map that data back into updated objects (response descriptor).

Check the example [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#object-serialization-tasks). It uses a dictionary to hold the updated attributes but the principle is the same. Using the dictionary just makes it easier to upload partial objects instead of full objects.